# sudo sane-find-scanner detects Viiscan vf3120 scanner, but sudo scanimage -L does not

Tags: 18.04, usb, scanner

Scanner: [Viisan VF3120](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DQYSNGQ), which is supposedly compatible with Linux.
I'm on LTS (Bionic).

```
root# sudo sane-find-scanner | grep libus 
found USB scanner (vendor=0x3297 [ZSA], product=0x1969 [Moonlander Mark I]) at libusb:003:007
found USB scanner (vendor=0x2e5a, product=0xd012, chip=GL848+) at libusb:003:034
```

It also for some reason detects my keyboard, the Moonlander.
The second line disappears when I turn off the scanner, which is the only hint I have that it is actually the scanner.

Though, it also changes a bit, but I guess that's normal for USB.

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x2e5a, product=0xd012, chip=GL848+) at libusb:003:042
```

This is the line from lsusb that only appears when the scanner is turned on.

```
root# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 036: ID 2e5a:d012
```

No luck with scanimage, though.

```
root# scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).

root# scanimage --version
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.27; backend version 1.0.27
```

Tried updating, but it made no difference.

```
root# add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-release
[..update upgrade]
root# scanimage --version
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.32; backend version 1.0.27
```

Tried manually adding the device to the config.

```
root# grep d012 /etc/sane.d/*conf
/etc/sane.d/snapscan.conf:usb 0x2e5a 0xd012
```

Did not help.

```
root# SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128 scanimage -L
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of snapscan to 128.
[snapscan] sane_snapscan_init
[snapscan] sane_snapscan_init: Snapscan backend version 1.4.53
[snapscan] add_usb_device(libusb:003:042)
[snapscan] add_usb_device: Detected (kind of) an USB device
[snapscan] snapscani_usb_open(libusb:003:042)
[snapscan] add_usb_device: Checking if 0x2e5a is a supported USB vendor ID
[snapscan] add_usb_device: USB vendor ID 0x2e5a is currently NOT supported by the snapscan backend.
[snapscan] snapscani_usb_close(1)
[snapscan] 1st read 0 write 0
[snapscan] 2nd read 0 write 0
[snapscan] sane_snapscan_get_devices (0x7ffe17e81320, 0)

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[snapscan] sane_snapscan_exit
```

Comment: Please give: `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`

Comment: I think **Viiscan** is a typo. It should be **Viisan**. Edit?

Comment: A lot of lines "Couldn't open device, some information will be missing" and one line "FIXME: alloc bigger buffer for device capability descriptors" are output by that command. Fixed the typo. Going to return the scanner, though, since the return period is very short.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scanner and it works nice, if I start `xsane` as root. Once your user is in group `scanner` and you have added a config file to `/etc/udev`, all will work fine.

Comment: Did all that and it didn't work, so I returned the scanner. Maybe by now some updates somewhere rectified this.